# Filter blanks from Xlookup search key range

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, lookup

I am using an xlookup function as an arrayformula to sum the prices of ingredients. It functions when the search key I use does not have any blank values, but if there are blank values it errors out. Please see these below screenshots:

Working
[image]

Not Working
[image]

What function can I add to allow for blanks under columns D through M?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Just leave the `xlookup` 4th parameter **`missing_value`** either blank OR zero & it should workout.*

```js
XLOOKUP(search_key, lookup_range, result_range, missing_value, match_mode, search_mode)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response because while leaving it blank wasn't working, I realized that the fourth option is missing_value and I can specify 0 for my formula instead of returning #N/A. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12405947

Comment: blank in the sense alike this: `=xlookup(D3:M3,A3:A268,H3:H268,)`